# The name does not exist in the current context (specific case)

Tags: c#, oop

I've seen a few questions but could not find a satisfatory answer. Please have a look at my code:

```
bool test = false;
if (ckb_benchmark.Checked == true)
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    test = true;
}


if (test == true)
{
    sw.Stop();
    string executionTime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " milliseconds";
    MessageBox.Show(executionTime, "Benchmark");
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to instantiate a Stopwatch class only under a certain condition. But Visual Studio tells me that  `sw` does not exist in that context. What's wrong here?

If I try to instantiate sw outside the first `if` statement, everything is fine.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you think is wrong? if you declare sw in the first `if` it is only available in that block (`block=>{....}`).

Comment: Take a look at the article about scopes on MSDN. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the `sw` instantiation outside of the `if` block but keeping the initialize statement...

```
bool test = false;
Stopwatch sw = null;

if (ckb_benchmark.Checked == true)
{
    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    test = true;
}


if (test == true && sw != null)
{
    sw.Stop();
    string executionTime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " milliseconds";
    MessageBox.Show(executionTime, "Benchmark");
}
```

P.S. this is just improving Grant Winney's answer after upvoting it

Comment: Great! This solves my problem. I actually did try to declare `sw` outside the if block but it resulted in another error: "Use of unassigned local variable sw ". Of course I didn't think about setting it to `null`. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you're only going to create the `Stopwatch` under a certain condition, then everything referencing that instance of the `Stopwatch` must also be inside the `if` block.

It's not enough to set `test = true` in the first `if` block. Once you exit the first `if` block, that instance of the `Stopwatch` goes out of scope and cannot be referenced.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reason for having a second `if` statement is that I have some code running right after the first one. And, naturally, I'd like the MessageBox to be shown only when that code is finished executing. What can I do about this?

Comment: Yes, it runs inside a `BackgroundWorker.DoWork` block. From what I can understand from your answer, I have two choices: To instantiate `Stopwatch` outside the first `if` statement, or to put all the code I want executed, followed by the `MessageBox` call, within that statement. Isn't there a way to test if `sw` exists, and use this test in the second statement?

Comment: This wouldn't be a good idea since the timing is only necessary if the user checks the `ckb_benchmark` checkbox. And also, the messagebox was requested by my client. But your answer, improved by Leo's, solved my problem.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say, the Stopwatch's purpose is to time the duration of a `while` loop, not the BackgroundWorker itself. And there is some heavy processing inside that loop. The first thing the loop do is to instantiate the Stopwatch; then it process some queries and finally, stops the Stopwatch and displays the MessageBox.